# Number of iterations performed by a for-loop in Julia

Tags: loops, for-loop, julia

Running the following script (via REPL `include("tmp.jl")`)

```
for n in 1:10
    println(n)
    if n > 3
        break
    end
end
println(n)
```

generates error

```
julia> include("tmp.jl")  
1  
2  
3  
4  
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: `n` not defined  
Stacktrace:  
 [1] top-level scope  
   @ ~/Documents/GMT_science/Julia/tmp.jl:7  
 [2] include(fname::String)  
   @ Base.MainInclude ./client.jl:478  
 [3] top-level scope  
   @ REPL[161]:1
```

I suppose the reason for that is that `n` is a local variable that doe snot exist outside of the scope of the loop.
**How can one access the number of iterations performed?** (e.g., when the number of iterations to satisfy the exit condition is not known beforehand.)

**Update**
A work-around way is defining a global variable keeping the value of the iteration index:

```
let m = 0
    for n in 1:10
        println(n)
        m = n
        if n > 3
            break
        end
    end
    println(m)
end
```

or using `while` loop:

```
let n = 1
    while n < 4
        println(n)
        n += 1
    end
    println(n)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `outer`:

```
julia> let n = 99.9
        for outer n in 1:10
           println(n)
           if n > 3
               break
           end
       end
       println("finally: ", n)
       end
1
2
3
4
finally: 4
```

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out a while-loop works fine. Another option is to use a Stateful Iterator (https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/iterators/#Base.Iterators.Stateful).

```
s = Iterators.Stateful(1:10)
for n in s
   println(n)
   if n > 3
        break
   end
end
```

To get the next element of the iteration you can then call `peek(s)`